# Rewrite rules in .htaccess get overwritten?

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

I'm not able to make it work by adding custom rewrite rules into `functions.php` or adding custom permastructures either. I have this code in my `.htaccess` that is working fine.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# BEGIN IPHONE RULES
RewriteRule ^mobile/([^/]+)$ mobile/index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
# END IPHONE RULES
# BEGIN PDF RULES
RewriteRule ^certificates/30-Days-Certificate-([0-9]+)$ pdf/index.php?type=30day&period=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^certificates/12-Month-Certificate$ pdf/index.php?type=12Month [QSA,L]
# END PDF RULES
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But every once a while it gets refreshed to defaults and I lose the iPhone and pdf rules. The mobile is called like this `/mobile/progress?userId=22&date=2011-02-21` where `progress` is the action and the others are just query vars. On the `.htaccess` is working fine but I can't manage to make it work by adding custom rules. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What did you try? Paste your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part between the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` will always be rewritten when the permalinks are flushed. You can either place your extra rewrite rules before this segment, or you can add register them in WordPress as *external rewrite rules*. If you flush your rules now (by visiting the *Permalinks* page, for example), your extra rules will be added to the `.htaccess` file.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse12708_init' );
function wpse12708_init()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_external_rule( 'mobile/([^/]+)$', 'mobile/index.php?action=$1' );
    $wp_rewrite->add_external_rule( 'certificates/30-Days-Certificate-([0-9]+)$', 'pdf/index.php?type=30day&period=$1' );
    $wp_rewrite->add_external_rule( 'certificates/12-Month-Certificate$', 'pdf/index.php?type=12Month' );
}
```

Comment: Wow Thanks, its almost working now. Before it was not adding a rule at all. <br/> Now Checking the htaccess file its adding the rules but its also adding a / into them. <br/> So instead of RewriteRule ^mobile/([^/]+)$ mobile/index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L] i have in the htaccess RewriteRule ^mobile/([^/]+)$ /mobile/index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]  . So im getting a 500 internal server error.

Comment: For what i saw if i edit the wp-includes/rewrite.php i can erase the $home_root var in order to remove the /, but it would be great to have a proper solution or at least know why its adding the /. Thanks again for all your helo

Comment: @chifliiiii: Ah indeed, WordPress prepends the `$home_root` for you. But this should not lead to an invalid `.htaccess` file. Do you also get the error when you go to `/mobile/index.php?action=[something]` directly?

Comment: no I Dont get any error by going direclty. IT could be that maybe its trying to go to www.someweb.com//mobile ? Becasue as soon as i remove the / its working fine

Comment: @chifliiiii: Do you have a directory `/mobile` with an `index.php` file at the root of your server filesystem? Because Apache will look there too if the replacement starts with a `/`. Adding `/` is normal, WordPress does it too in the `/index.php` redirection.

Comment: @Jan I have a mobile directory in the root with an index.php file in it.

Comment: @chifliiiii: At the root of your real filesystem on the server, or only in the `DocumentRoot` of Apache? I think you will get better results if you ask this part of your question again on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/), a site dedicated to server administration.